# GridBagLayout components change when JFrame is undecorated

Tags: java, swing, jframe, components, gridbaglayout

I am using a `GridBagLayout` (3x1) to display the login screen for a program I am making. The layout and everything in it looks fine and how it is suppose to when the `JFrame` is decorated. Everything resizes perfectly whether or not the JFrame is full screen.
What it should look like:
[image: What it should look like]

**The problem is when I do `frame.setUndecorated(true)`. This seems to resize some of the components for no reason.**
 I checked the size of all the components and nothing is changing, just the layout of the components.
I just want it to look the same way when it is in full screen because this application will be in full screen most of the time. Why is this resizing happening and how can I prevent it? Thanks in advance.

Picture of the problem:
[image: Problem]

Here is the (condensed) code:

```
package main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Transparency;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().add(new MainView());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setSize(900, 900);
        frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        frame.setUndecorated(true); // Problem is here
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MainView extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

    private ScalableImage backgroundImage;

    private final JPanel loginPanel;
    private final GridBagConstraints spgbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    private final JLabel loginLabel;
    private final JTextField loginField;
    private final JButton loginButton;

    private final JButton adminButton;

    private final GridBagConstraints gbc;

    private static final double[] colweights = { 1, .5, .05 };
    private static final double[] rowweights = { 1, .5, 0 };

    public MainView() {
        super();

        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        setOpaque(false);

        loginPanel = new JPanel();

        loginLabel = new JLabel("<html>&nbsp&nbsp Login to Volunteer Account</html>");

        loginField = new JTextField("Enter ID Here...");
        loginField.setToolTipText("Enter volunteer ID");
        loginField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                loginButton.doClick();
            }
        });

        loginButton = new JButton("Enter");

        adminButton = new JButton("Admin");
        adminButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        adminButton.setToolTipText("Click here if you're an admin");

        layoutView();

        addMouseListener(this);

        revalidate();
    }

    public void layoutView() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weighty = rowweights[0];
        gbc.weightx = colweights[0];
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        this.add(new JComponent() {
        }, gbc);

        layoutLoginPanel();

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = rowweights[1];
        gbc.weightx = colweights[1];
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 3;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        this.add(loginPanel, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.weighty = rowweights[2];
        gbc.weightx = colweights[2];
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHEAST;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        gbc.ipadx = 100;
        gbc.ipady = 100;
        this.add(adminButton, gbc);

        gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = 3;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.ipadx = 0;
        gbc.ipady = 0;

        Image img = new ImageIcon(
                "C:/Users/akars/Documents/Eclipse Projects/FreeGeek Volunteering/resources/images/freegeek_frontdesk.jpg")
                        .getImage();
        backgroundImage = new ScalableImage(img, false);
        backgroundImage.setOpaque(true);
        this.add(backgroundImage, gbc);

    }

    private void layoutLoginPanel() {
        loginPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        spgbc.weightx = 1;
        spgbc.weighty = 0;
        spgbc.gridx = 0;
        spgbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        spgbc.insets = new Insets(8, 8, 8, 8);

        spgbc.gridy = 0;
        loginPanel.add(loginLabel, spgbc);

        spgbc.gridy = 1;
        loginPanel.add(loginField, spgbc);

        spgbc.gridy = 2;
        spgbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        spgbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        spgbc.ipady = 20;
        spgbc.ipadx = 20;
        loginPanel.add(loginButton, spgbc);

        loginPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(getDarkerColor(loginPanel.getBackground(), 100), 3, true));
        loginPanel.setOpaque(true);
    }

    public Color getDarkerColor(Color col, int num) {
        return new Color(col.getRed() - num, col.getGreen() - num, col.getBlue() - num);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        MainView.this.grabFocus();
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }
}

class ScalableImage extends JPanel {

    private Image master;
    private boolean toFit;
    private Image scaled;

    public ScalableImage(Image master) {
        this(master, true);
    }

    public ScalableImage(Image master, boolean toFit) {
        this.master = master;
        setToFit(toFit);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return master == null ? super.getPreferredSize() : new Dimension(master.getWidth(this), master.getHeight(this));
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Image toDraw = null;
        if (scaled != null) {
            toDraw = scaled;
        } else if (master != null) {
            toDraw = master;
        }

        if (toDraw != null) {
            int x = (getWidth() - toDraw.getWidth(this)) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - toDraw.getHeight(this)) / 2;
            g.drawImage(toDraw, x, y, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void invalidate() {
        generateScaledInstance();
        super.invalidate();
    }

    private boolean isToFit() {
        return toFit;
    }

    private void setToFit(boolean value) {
        if (value != toFit) {
            toFit = value;
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    private void generateScaledInstance() {
        scaled = null;
        if (isToFit()) {
            scaled = getScaledInstanceToFit(master, getSize());
        } else {
            scaled = getScaledInstanceToFill(master, getSize());
        }
    }

    private BufferedImage toBufferedImage(Image master) {
        Dimension masterSize = new Dimension(master.getWidth(this), master.getHeight(this));
        BufferedImage image = createCompatibleImage(masterSize);
        Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();
        g2d.drawImage(master, 0, 0, this);
        g2d.dispose();
        return image;
    }

    private Image getScaledInstanceToFit(Image master, Dimension size) {
        Dimension masterSize = new Dimension(master.getWidth(this), master.getHeight(this));
        return getScaledInstance(toBufferedImage(master), getScaleFactorToFit(masterSize, size),
                RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR, true);
    }

    private Image getScaledInstanceToFill(Image master, Dimension size) {
        Dimension masterSize = new Dimension(master.getWidth(this), master.getHeight(this));
        return getScaledInstance(toBufferedImage(master), getScaleFactorToFill(masterSize, size),
                RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR, true);
    }

    public Dimension getSizeToFit(Dimension original, Dimension toFit) {
        double factor = getScaleFactorToFit(original, toFit);
        Dimension size = new Dimension(original);
        size.width *= factor;
        size.height *= factor;
        return size;
    }

    public Dimension getSizeToFill(Dimension original, Dimension toFit) {
        double factor = getScaleFactorToFill(original, toFit);
        Dimension size = new Dimension(original);
        size.width *= factor;
        size.height *= factor;
        return size;
    }

    private double getScaleFactor(int iMasterSize, int iTargetSize) {
        return (double) iTargetSize / (double) iMasterSize;
    }

    private double getScaleFactorToFit(Dimension original, Dimension toFit) {
        double dScale = 1d;
        if (original != null && toFit != null) {
            double dScaleWidth = getScaleFactor(original.width, toFit.width);
            double dScaleHeight = getScaleFactor(original.height, toFit.height);
            dScale = Math.min(dScaleHeight, dScaleWidth);
        }
        return dScale;
    }

    private double getScaleFactorToFill(Dimension masterSize, Dimension targetSize) {
        double dScaleWidth = getScaleFactor(masterSize.width, targetSize.width);
        double dScaleHeight = getScaleFactor(masterSize.height, targetSize.height);

        return Math.max(dScaleHeight, dScaleWidth);
    }

    private BufferedImage createCompatibleImage(Dimension size) {
        return createCompatibleImage(size.width, size.height);
    }

    private BufferedImage createCompatibleImage(int width, int height) {
        GraphicsConfiguration gc = getGraphicsConfiguration();
        if (gc == null) {
            gc = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();
        }

        BufferedImage image = gc.createCompatibleImage(width, height, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);
        image.coerceData(true);
        return image;
    }

    private BufferedImage getScaledInstance(BufferedImage img, double dScaleFactor, Object hint, boolean bHighQuality) {
        BufferedImage imgScale = img;
        int iImageWidth = (int) Math.round(img.getWidth() * dScaleFactor);
        int iImageHeight = (int) Math.round(img.getHeight() * dScaleFactor);

        if (dScaleFactor <= 1.0d) {
            imgScale = getScaledDownInstance(img, iImageWidth, iImageHeight, hint, bHighQuality);
        } else {
            imgScale = getScaledUpInstance(img, iImageWidth, iImageHeight, hint, bHighQuality);
        }

        return imgScale;
    }

    private BufferedImage getScaledDownInstance(BufferedImage img, int targetWidth, int targetHeight, Object hint,
            boolean higherQuality) {

        int type = (img.getTransparency() == Transparency.OPAQUE) ? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB
                : BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB;

        BufferedImage ret = img;

        if (targetHeight > 0 || targetWidth > 0) {
            int w, h;
            if (higherQuality) {
                // Use multi-step technique: start with original size, then
                // scale down in multiple passes with drawImage()
                // until the target size is reached
                w = img.getWidth();
                h = img.getHeight();
            } else {
                // Use one-step technique: scale directly from original
                // size to target size with a single drawImage() call
                w = targetWidth;
                h = targetHeight;
            }

            do {
                if (higherQuality && w > targetWidth) {
                    w /= 2;
                    if (w < targetWidth) {
                        w = targetWidth;
                    }
                }
                if (higherQuality && h > targetHeight) {
                    h /= 2;
                    if (h < targetHeight) {
                        h = targetHeight;
                    }
                }

                BufferedImage tmp = new BufferedImage(Math.max(w, 1), Math.max(h, 1), type);
                Graphics2D g2 = tmp.createGraphics();
                g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, hint);
                g2.drawImage(ret, 0, 0, w, h, null);
                g2.dispose();

                ret = tmp;
            } while (w != targetWidth || h != targetHeight);
        } else {
            ret = new BufferedImage(1, 1, type);
        }

        return ret;
    }

    private BufferedImage getScaledUpInstance(BufferedImage img, int targetWidth, int targetHeight, Object hint,
            boolean higherQuality) {

        int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB;

        BufferedImage ret = img;
        int w, h;
        if (higherQuality) {
            w = img.getWidth();
            h = img.getHeight();
        } else {
            w = targetWidth;
            h = targetHeight;
        }

        do {
            if (higherQuality && w < targetWidth) {
                w *= 2;
                if (w > targetWidth) {
                    w = targetWidth;
                }
            }

            if (higherQuality && h < targetHeight) {
                h *= 2;
                if (h > targetHeight) {
                    h = targetHeight;
                }
            }

            BufferedImage tmp = new BufferedImage(w, h, type);
            Graphics2D g2 = tmp.createGraphics();
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, hint);
            g2.drawImage(ret, 0, 0, w, h, null);
            g2.dispose();

            ret = tmp;
            tmp = null;
        } while (w != targetWidth || h != targetHeight);
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Here is the (condensed) code:` - that is not condensed code. Your question is about a layout manager. You have all kinds of strange code realated to scaling the image. Is that code the problem? Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. So use an image at its actual size. See if it works. If not, then you have a SSCCE to post. If it does work, then you have narrowed down the problem and you need to look at your scaling logic.

Comment: I might consider using something more `private static final double[] colweights = {0.5, .45, .05};` for the `colweights`